# Evaluating a polynomial using the computer algebra system Singular

Tags: computer-algebra-systems, singular-cas

I recently started learning the computer algebra system Singular. Working through some early exercises of the book "A Singular introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Gert-Martin Greuel and Gerhard Pfister I wasn't able to find way to actually evaluate a polynomial defined in a arbitrary ring.
Using the online manual as well as looking through some Singular-libraries wasn't helpfull at all for me finding any procedure or way to evaluate a polynomial.

It seems that's either impossible or it is so obvious that there is no hint in the book and the manual how to do this.

I'm sure there must be a way to do such things in a computer algebra system like Singular?

---

An example what I'm aiming to do:

After defining a ring, such as

```
ring A = 0,(x,y),dp;
poly f = x2 + y;
```

Now calling

```
f(1,2);
```

leads to

```
? `f(1)` is undefined
? error occurred in or before STDIN line 3: `f(1,2);`
```

Any usual/intuitive way of setting values to the variables x and y like

```
x := 1;
```

with or without the dots causes the error:

```
? error occurred in or before STDIN line 4: `x:=1;`
skipping text from `1`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The way to go is using the function `subst` like this:

```
ring A = 0,(x,y), dp;
poly f = x2 + y; 
subst(f,x,1,y,2);
```

which will result in

```
3
```